# Setting MDI child transparency possible? VB.net

Tags: vb.net, mdi

Form 1 has a transparency key for custom title bar with a background image.

I set the child forms(Inside the MDIclient) back color the same with the transparency key I set for the parent. Now its like making a hole in that area.

Is it possible to set the child form back color to transparent? so that the parent form background image visible within that form... thanks for your answers...

Comment: You will need to use different values for the TransparencyKey property.

Comment: i already have.. but its showing grey... not transparent...

Comment: Yes, the MdiClient window is dark gray.  It works.  If you want to see something else then you'll have to set the BackgroundImage property of the MdiClient window.

Comment: The mdi client has already a background image.. I dont know why.. If I remove the form out of that mdi client.. Eveything is ok.. But if its inside... it shows grey..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Solved**] my own problem.

Just for sharing..

Put this in the constructor of the child form

```
Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
Me.BackColor = Color.Transparent
```